# SQL remove nanoseconds form @timedate

Tags: sql-server

I've a small little SQL script to backup our database and transaction logs.

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);
SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(Varchar(256),GETDATE(), 126), ':','_');

DECLARE @location VARCHAR(100) = '\\pathtoserver\D3P_DB_' + @timedate + '.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE D3P 
    TO DISK = @location 
    WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUN-LOAD, STATS=10, CHECKSUM
```

The command `@TimeDate` produces a output like this

```
26 Sep 2017 11:49:07:650
```

I want to get rid of the milliseconds at the end. How can I implement this into my SQL script?

Comment: Your ultimate goal is to generate current time as `26 Sep 2017 11:49:07` or to parse an existing string you cannot change? Are you adapting SQL Server code to MySQL?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález my goal is to remove the nanosecond from the filename. For now all the backups are named like this xxx2023-01-12T16_00_00.683.bkp. I don't need the nanosecond in the filename because it's confusing to read. All the code is above. There is nothing more than that.

Comment: you want to remove milliseconds not nanoseconds

Comment: If you don't want the milliseconds, why not `CAST`/`CONVERT` the date and time value to a `datetime2(0)`? Or (probably better) why not use a `varchar(19)` instead of defining the value as an overly large `varchar(256)`?

Answer (score -1):

I've changed line 2

```
DECLARE @TimeDate Varchar(256);
SET @TimeDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),GETDATE(), 126), ':','_');
DECLARE @location VARCHAR(100) = '\\pathtoserver\D3P_DB_' + @timedate + '.bak'
BACKUP DATABASE D3P TO DISK = @location WITH NOFORMAT, INIT, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUN-LOAD, STATS=10, CHECKSUM
```

Comment: A style code is when converting a string based datatype to a non-string one, or vice-versa. This won't maintain the format the OP wants here.

Comment: @Larnu this doesn't work. The filename looks like this -> DB_2023-01-13 08_29_20.bak2023-01-13 08_29_20.bak

Comment: I know it wouldn't, I said so in the above comment, @BehindYou . I'm not the one who wrote this answer.